# Number of required passes to fully sort using BubbleSort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm investigating the mathematics behind the number of passes required to sort each of the possible combinations of integers `[1,n]` in an `array[n]`.

For example, with `n = 3`, there are `3! = 6` possible permutations of the numbers:

```
1,2,3 - 1,3,2 - 2,1,3 - 2,3,1 - 3,1,2 - 3,2,1.
```

- One of these initial permutations requires `k = 0` passes `(1,2,3)` to sort the array into ascending order;
- Three of them require `k = 1` pass `(1,3,2 - 2,1,3 - 3,1,2)` and
- Two require `k = 2` passes `(2,3,1 - 3,2,1)`.

Basically, I want to be able to derive mathematically the set of numbers of passes `{k}` for a given `n`.

For `n = 4`, the number of initial permutations, P, that require k passes is `P(n,k) = 1,7,10,6 for k = 0,1,2,3`.

There is of course only ever 1 initial permutation for k = 0 (already in ascending order), ie `P(n,0) = 1`, and the number of initial permutations for the highest value of k (which is n-1) is k!, ie `P(n,n-1) = (n-1)!` . Or, at least I think so...

I feel like this is simpler than I'm making it and involves factorial formulae.

Comment: I would start with the most basic observation: how far can some element be shifted within one pass (1) and how far does some element need to be shifted in the worst-case (n-1 times; if it's totally out of order). This already gets you a lower-bound. Now for the upper-bound, some more proof-work will be needed.

Comment: My first observation is that this depends on the implementation of the sort. for example if you have [1,2,3,0] and are iterating from left to right only, then 3 passes are needed, whereas if you're doing a right to left or back and forth implementation it ends up with one or two passes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  See [here[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).  We expect that you attempt your own research before posting to SO.

Comment: lol Prune I hope this was an automated comment, my post ticks all those boxes just fine thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm for generating permutations is [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm). This code is a brute-force method to calculate the permutations of `n` objects. For each configuration, the number of passes is the maximum length any element is from it's sorted position, `O(n)`. Given `n`, this gives all the the `P(n, k)` by doing a histogram; it's running time is exponential in `n`, (in C.)

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <assert.h> /* assert */
#include <errno.h>  /* errno, ERANGE */

typedef void (*PermuteFunc)(const size_t a_size);

unsigned a[12];
const size_t a_max = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

/* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm#cite_note-3 */
static void heaps_r(const size_t a_size, const unsigned k,
    const PermuteFunc func) {
    size_t i, j;
    assert(k && a_size);
    if(k == 1) { func(a_size); return; }
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        heaps_r(a_size, k - 1, func);
        if(i >= k - 1) continue;
        j = (k & 1) ? 0 : i; /* Odd/even. */
        a[j] ^= a[k-1], a[k-1] ^= a[j], a[j] ^= a[k-1]; /* Swap. */
    }
}

/* Generates all permutations of size `a_size` and passes them to `func`.
 @return Success. */
static int heaps(const size_t a_size, const PermuteFunc func) {
    size_t i;
    assert(func);
    if(!a_size || a_size > a_max) return errno = ERANGE, 0;
    for(i = 0; i < a_size; i++) a[i] = i + 1; /* Distinct numbers. */
    heaps_r(a_size, a_size, func);
    return 1;
}

static unsigned histogram[256]; /* This is good enough, right? */
static size_t histogram_size = sizeof histogram / sizeof *histogram;

/* @implements PermuteFunc */
static void print(const size_t a_size) {
    size_t i, bin = 0;
    assert(a && a_size);
    for(i = 0; i < a_size; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
#if 0 /* I misread the question. */
    /* O(n^2) way to calculate the Kendall tau distance. */
    for(i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        size_t j;
        for(j = i + 1; j < a_size; j++) if(a[i] > a[j]) bin++;
    }
#else
    /* Calculate the number of passes bubble-sort needs to make. */
    for(i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        size_t passes = abs(a[i] - i);
        if(passes > bin) bin = passes;
    }
#endif
    if(bin >= histogram_size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Histogram too small for %d.\n", (unsigned long)bin);
        return;
    }
    histogram[bin]++;
    printf("-> %d\n", bin);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n;
    size_t k;
    const char *err = 0;
    do {
        if(argc != 2 || (n = atoi(argv[1]), n <= 0))
            { errno = EDOM; err = "Argument needed"; break; }
        if(!heaps(n, &print)) { err = "Heap's"; break; }
        printf("\n");
        for(k = 0; k < histogram_size; k++) if(histogram[k])
            printf("P(%d, %lu) = %u\n", n, (unsigned long)k, histogram[k]);
    } while(0);
    return err ? (perror(err), EXIT_FAILURE) : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Passing 4, I get,

```
P(4, 1) = 1
P(4, 2) = 7
P(4, 3) = 10
P(4, 4) = 6
```

I Googled the Kendall tau distance code and notice that it's the [coefficients in expansion of Product_{i=0..n-1} (1 + x + ... + x^i)](https://oeis.org/A008302), however the code with the passes of bubble-sort doesn't match any documents.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if there was a faster way to do this; you might ask on computer science.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation:
if you're only going in one direction, then any element will move at most one step closer to it's destination when it's destination is in the direction opposite to the iteration direction. Therefore, the number of iterations needed is determined by the maximum distance any single element needs to move in that direction.

If you're iterating back and forth, it's less obvious. I suspect by converting to a directed graph (where each edge points to other elements that need to be swapped with it), a property of the edges will give the answer.